# Targeting JSON internal array data and using RKValueTransformer in RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I'm using RestKit on iOS to retrieve some data from kraken.com

I have the following JSON data:

```
{
    "error":[],
    "result":{
        "XXBTZUSD":{
            "a":["475.00000","1"],
            "b":["465.00639","2"],
            "c":["475.00000","0.01000389"],
            "v":["1.01078477","1.01078477"],
            "p":["475.00008","475.00008"],
            "t":[6,6],
            "l":["475.00000","475.00000"],
            "h":["475.00013","475.00013"],
            "o":"475.00001"
        }
    }
}
```

My keyPath is `@"result.XXBTZUSD"` and I'm interested in the first member of the array in each property, i.e. `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, and so on with the exception of `'o'` as its value isn't an array. To be clear, an example value I'm interested in would be `"475.00000"` for `'a'`. I am trying to map these values to `NSNumber` properties in my own data model.

Aside:
I would be doing this dynamically, as I am also getting similar data from other sources but with different structured data.

Also, I don't believe I can use `RKObjectMappingMatcher`s because I don't have an "expected value" for this data.

**EDIT:**

I've continued working on my `RKDynamicMapping` and `RKBlockValueTransformer` logic:

```
RKDynamicMapping *dynamicMapping = [RKDynamicMapping new];
[dynamicMapping setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock:^RKObjectMapping *(id representation)
{
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:class];

    if ([url.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"https://api.kraken.com"])
    {
        RKBlockValueTransformer *arrayToNumberValueTransformer = [RKBlockValueTransformer valueTransformerWithValidationBlock:^BOOL(__unsafe_unretained Class inputValueClass, __unsafe_unretained Class outputValueClass) {
            BOOL isTransformableValue = NO;
            if ([inputValueClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSArray class]] && [outputValueClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
            {
                isTransformableValue = YES;
            }
            return isTransformableValue;
        } transformationBlock:^BOOL(id inputValue, __autoreleasing id *outputValue, __unsafe_unretained Class outputClass, NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {
            RKValueTransformerTestInputValueIsKindOfClass(inputValue, [NSArray class], error);
            RKValueTransformerTestOutputValueClassIsSubclassOfClass(outputClass, [NSNumber class], error);

            *outputValue = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:[[inputValue objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue]];

            return YES;
        }];

        arrayToNumberValueTransformer.name = @"ArrayToNumberValueTransformer";
        [[RKValueTransformer defaultValueTransformer] insertValueTransformer:arrayToNumberValueTransformer atIndex:0];
    }

    if (sourceKeyPath && [sourceKeyPath length] > 0)
    {
        //  Special case (ignore):
        if ([url.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"http://blockchain.info"])
        {
            [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{sourceKeyPath:@"currencyCode"}];
        }

        //
        //  The following is useful if you're expecting a set but the service returns a single value
        //[mapping setForceCollectionMapping:YES];    // RestKit cannot infer this information on its own
        //
    }

    //  Where a 'key' is the JSON representation and its value is the internal object representation
    NSDictionary *attributeMappings = [query objectForKey:@"attributeMappings"];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:attributeMappings];

    return mapping;
}];
```

**EDIT:**

I've got data being mapped now however I'm not sure that I am inserting my `RKBlockValueTransformer` into the default value transformers list properly? If I insert at `0` will I break something with the functionality of other default value transformers?

Comment: Have you looked at nil key path mappings and a custom `RKValueTransformer`?

Comment: I've made an attempt at what you've suggested. Any further thoughts?

Comment: Regarding nil key path mappings... Are you suggesting that I traverse a dictionary instead since what's being returned is a set of attribute-value pairs? I feel like that may produce more difficult code to work with.

Comment: Can't you just forloop on ``objectAtIndex:0`` if ``array count > 1`` ? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I could choose to `addValueTransformer:` instead but from other examples I've seen, they've been inserting them. Also looping isn't an option as the internal structure of RKValueTransformer is controlled at a lower level.

Comment: That's what I've done. Opted to go with `addValueTransformer:` instead as it still works :)

Comment: Good work, well done. If you set `mapping.valueTransformer` then you don't need to add a default transformer.