# Swift. Mapping from JSON to object model. Array of Array

Tags: ios, swift, restkit

There's model in  JSON    format

```
{
    "offline": false,
    "data": {
        "path": [
            [ {
                    "Latitude": 56.789351316653,
                    "Longitude": 60.6053340947616
                }, {
                    "Latitude": 56.78674,
                    "Longitude": 60.60613
                }
            ], [ {
                    "Latitude": 56.79071,
                    "Longitude": 60.60492
                }, {
                    "Latitude": 56.79129,
                    "Longitude": 60.60493
                } ]
        ] } }
```

and object model on swift

http://pastebin.com/j0mK8eYG

Issue: can't parse the path field of json, because there is an array of arrays.
In the case of arrays with single dimension all works well.

Comment: Why does the JSON contain an array of arrays?

Comment: @Wain because it is a server model

Comment: Logically, what do the nested arrays represent? Are there always 2 items in the inner arrays? Why isn't a similar structure used on the client (or is that actually your goal)?

Comment: @Wain, it's just example, I can't change structure

Comment: Look at creating a custom value transformer

Comment: @Wain you can tell more, I'm newest in swift and ios development

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903450/targeting-json-internal-array-data-and-using-rkvaluetransformer-in-restkit

Comment: @Wain, It caused more questions. You can show me in swift. I'm an android developer, and the language is not familiar to me. I don't understand some of the language constructs.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar. I looked at the implementation of mtl_JSONArrayTransformerWithModelClass which transforms an array of dictionaries to and from an array of MTLModels. So I made a similar transformer which expects an array of array of dictionaries/MTLModels. I iterate over the outermost array and transform each array of dictionaries with the mtl_JSONArrayTransformerWithModelClass.

```
+ (NSValueTransformer *)JSONArrayOfArraysTransformerWithModelClass:(Class)modelClass

NSValueTransformer *arrayTransformer = [NSValueTransformer mtl_JSONArrayTransformerWithModelClass:modelClass];

return [MTLValueTransformer
      reversibleTransformerWithForwardBlock:^id(NSArray *arrays) {
        if (arrays == nil) return nil;

        NSAssert([arrays isKindOfClass:NSArray.class], @"Expected an array, got: %@", arrays);

        NSMutableArray *modelArrays = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[arrays count]];
        for (id JSONArray in arrays) {
          if (JSONArray == NSNull.null) {
            [modelArrays addObject:JSONArray];
            continue;
          }

          NSAssert([JSONArray isKindOfClass:NSArray.class], @"Expected an array of arrays of dictionaries, got array of: %@", JSONArray);

          NSArray *modelArray = [arrayTransformer transformedValue:JSONArray];
          if (modelArray == nil) continue;

          [modelArrays addObject:modelArray];
        }

        return modelArrays;
      }
      reverseBlock:^id(NSArray *arrays) {
        if (arrays == nil) return nil;

        NSAssert([arrays isKindOfClass:NSArray.class], @"Expected an array of arrays of MTLModels, got: %@", arrays);

        NSMutableArray *modelArrays = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:modelArrays.count];
        for (id modelArray in arrays) {
          if (modelArray == NSNull.null) {
            [modelArrays addObject:NSNull.null];
            continue;
          }

          NSAssert([modelArray isKindOfClass:NSArray.class], @"Expected an array of arrays, got array of: %@", modelArray);

          NSArray *array = [arrayTransformer reverseTransformedValue:modelArray];
          if (array == nil) continue;

          [modelArrays addObject:array];
        }

        return modelArrays;
      }];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to use a third party :** There is this awesome and cleanly implemented open source [objectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper), works with Alamofire as well. 
Create models implementing protocol "Mappable" and custom arrays will be handled according to the Class specified.
Reduces boiler plate code like anything.

**If you want to parse it on your own** : Simply create a helper method in your mdoel class to parse it using for loop.

```
init (responseDict: [String: Any]) {
    var itemModels : [ItemClass] = []
    let itemDictArray = responseDict["items"] as! [[String:Any]]

    for itemDict in itemDictArray {
        itemModels.append(ItemClass.init(dict: (itemDict as [String:Any]) ))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - Generate the Swift models by copying the same Json at http://www.json4swift.com

2 - Copy the generated files to your project

3 - Open Data.swift, replace the following method

```
required public init?(dictionary: NSDictionary) {
if (dictionary["path"] != nil) { path = Path.modelsFromDictionaryArray(dictionary["path"] as! NSArray) }
}
```

to

```
required public init?(dictionary: NSDictionary) {
if let paths = dictionary["path"] as? NSArray {

    let allPaths = NSMutableArray()
    for patharr in paths {
        allPaths.addObjectsFromArray(Path.modelsFromDictionaryArray(patharr as! NSArray))
    }

}
}
```

4 - Success!